# How to create countup timer with keyboard events in js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keydown, keyup

I am creating a program where the timer starts when i hit "keyup" and stops when i hit "keydown" and resets the timer when i hit "keydown" next time.

```
const Timer = () => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  let state = 0;
  let isFired = false;
  const increment = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
      if (isFired) {
        if (e.code === 'Space' && state === 2) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          isFired = false;
          handleReset();
        }

        if (e.code === 'Space' && state === 1) {
          clearInterval(increment.current);
          state = 2;
        }
      }
    });

    window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
      if (!isFired) {
        if (e.code === 'Space' && state === 0) {
          isFired = true;
          state = 1;
          handleStart();
        }
      }
    });

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keydown', handleReset);
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', handleStart);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleStart = () => {
    increment.current = setInterval(() => {
    // DON'T COPY THIS BIT
      setTimer((timer) => timer + 10);
    }, 10);
  };

  const handleReset = () => {
    clearInterval(increment.current);
    setTimer(0);
    state = 0;
  };
  // DON'T COPY THIS BIT

  const formatTime = () => {
    console.log(timer);
    const getMilliSeconds = `0${timer % 60}`.slice(-2);
    const seconds = `${Math.floor(timer / 60)}`;
    const getSeconds = `0${seconds % 60}`.slice(-2);
    const getMinutes = `0${Math.floor(timer / 3600)}`.slice(-2);

    // return `${getHours} : ${getMinutes} : ${getSeconds}`;
    if (getMinutes === '00') {
      return `${getSeconds}.${getMilliSeconds}`;
    } else {
      return `${getMinutes} : ${getSeconds} : ${getMilliSeconds} `;
    }
  };

  // const formatTime = () => {
  //   // const milliSeconds = `0${}`;
  //   const seconds = `0${Math.floor(timer / 100)}`;
  //   const minute = `0${Math.floor(timer / 3600)}`.slice(-2);

  //   return `${minute}.${seconds}`;
  // };

  return (
    <div className="Timer">
      <h1>{formatTime()}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

i have tried this so far
it works most of the time but sometimes it gets glitchy
and i know the time is not formated properly and also the increment is also wrong. Sometimes it stops on the "keydown" and fires the "keyup" in the same stroke making it reset the timer starting from zero I don't exactly know that if it fires keyup on the same stroke but it seems like it does

this is a link to what i have done so far [timer](https://eager-franklin-97289d.netlify.app/)

Comment: what did you try for now ?

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and found it needs too many changes.

1. You are using `state` and `isFired` as variables only but you need their persisted values on rerendering. Therefore, these must be states.
2. You are not unbinding the same listener which you binded on `keyup` and `keydown`.
3. As per your current code, your timer will start on 1st `keyup` and then next `keydown` it will stop as such where it was. Now, on next `keydown` it will reset to 0 and then on `keyup`, again timer will start from 0.

I modified your code and see working changes here,

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-shannon-im8zt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Bro thank you so much I really appreciate it. I was doing a project and I was stuck here from yesterday.